# Segmentation fault (core dumped) runtime error in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

Hi so I am new to C and just wrote my first program in the language and keep getting the segmentation fault error when I try to run it. I'm sure there are multiple small mistakes I have made throughout the code. I have gone through it and I can't figure out where my mistake is. Here is my code:

```
// $Id: crpn.c,v 1.1 2013-10-22 13:28:04-07 - - $

#include <assert.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int exit_status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
#define EMPTY (-1)
#define SIZE 16

typedef struct stack stack;
struct stack {
   int top;
   int capacity;
   int size;
   double numbers[SIZE];
};

void bad_operator (const char *oper) {
   fflush (NULL);
   fprintf (stderr, "oper=\"%s\"\n", oper);
   fflush (NULL);
   exit_status = EXIT_FAILURE;
   printf("%s: invaild operator\n", oper);
}

void push (stack *the_stack, double number) {
   if (the_stack->size == the_stack->capacity) {
        printf("%a:stack overflow", number);
    }
   else {
        the_stack->numbers[the_stack->size++]=number;
    }
}

void do_binop (stack *the_stack, char oper) {
  if ((the_stack->top)<1) {
        printf("oper=\"%c\":stack underflow\n", oper);
    }
   else {
        double right = the_stack->numbers[the_stack->size--];
        double left = the_stack->numbers[the_stack->size--];
        switch (oper) {
            case '+': push (the_stack, left + right); break;
            case '-': push (the_stack, left - right); break;
            case '*': push (the_stack, left * right); break;
            case '/': push (the_stack, left / right); break;
          }
        }
}

void do_print (stack *the_stack) {
   if (the_stack->top == -1) {
       printf("stack is empty\n");
    }
   else {
       int pos;
       for (pos = 0; pos <= the_stack->top; ++pos) {
          printf("%a\n",the_stack->numbers[pos]);
   }
 }
}

void do_clear (stack *the_stack) {
   the_stack->top = -1;
}

void do_operator (stack *the_stack, const char *oper) {
   switch (oper[0] ) {
         case '+': do_binop (the_stack, '+'); break;
         case '-': do_binop (the_stack, '-'); break;
         case '*': do_binop (the_stack, '*'); break;
         case '/': do_binop (the_stack, '/'); break;
         case ';': do_print (the_stack);      break;
         case '@': do_clear (the_stack);      break;
         default : bad_operator (oper);       break;
   }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
   if (argc != 1) {
      fprintf (stderr, "Usage: %s\n", basename (argv[0]));
      fflush (NULL);
      exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   stack the_stack;
   the_stack.top = EMPTY;
   char buffer[1024];
   for (;;) {
      int scanrc = scanf ("%1023s", buffer);
      if (scanrc == EOF) break;
      assert (scanrc == 1);
      if (buffer[0] == '#') {
         scanrc = scanf ("%1023[^\n]", buffer);
         continue;
      }
      char *endptr;
      double number = strtod (buffer, &endptr);
      if (*endptr == '\0') {
         push (&the_stack, number);
      }else if (buffer[1] != '\0') {
         bad_operator (buffer);
      }else {
         do_operator (&the_stack, buffer);
      }
   }
   return exit_status;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Let me "teach you to fish":

A debugger will tell you exactly where the fault is. If you're using an IDE (Xcode, Eclipse, VS) it has a nice interface to one and you should use that. If not:

Compile your program with the `-g` switch: `gcc -g mycode.c`. This adds debugging information to the executable (makes the debugger give you much better info).

```
$ gdb my_executable
...
> run
...
Segmentation fault
> where
```

This will give you the exact location (which function on which line number).

Comment: It's pretty common that segmentation faults occur on a different line from the one with the problem.  Writing through a bad pointer trashes the heap or stack, which causes a segmentation fault some time later.

Comment: Incidentally, usually `bt` is way more useful than just `where`.

Comment: @Barmar It happens, but in the vast vast majority of cases the segfaulting line has some connection to the bug. It's better to have a lead to investigate than to just sit and stare at your code.

Comment: Look at the answers Paul Griffiths and I gave. The error is in `main()` (where the structure should be initialized), but the crash will happen in `push()` if you're lucky, or somewhere totally random if you're not. So the debugger won't tell you where the error is, you need to do additional detective work to figure out why the variables don't contain what you expected. I'm all for teaching people to fish, but all you did was hand them a rod and say "Now go fishing".

Comment: @Barmar when I tried it on OP's code it took me directly to the line Paul quotes. That's a great start to the debug process in my book.

Comment: That's my point: it's just a start. Now teach him how to get from there to the lines in `main()` that caused the error.

Comment: @Barmar the way OP's paragraph is worded it sounds like all he needs is a start. That error line is a great pointer in the right direction. To me it sounds like he knows how to take it from there, and now he has a powerful tool in his debugging arsenal. I agree that you and Paul give good advice beyond the cause of this particular segfault. My advice compliments yours. I don't understand your violent opposition to it.

Comment: Based on the mistakes in his program, I think the OP is totally clueless, and wouldn't know how to take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You're never initializing `the_stack.size` and `the_stack.capacity`.

```
stack the_stack;
the_stack.top = EMPTY;
the_stack.size = 0;
the_stack.capacity = SIZE;
```

It's also not clear what the intended difference between `top` and `size` is. The `push` function increments `size`, but `do_binop` and `do_print` use `top`, which is never incremented.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this, in your `push()` function:

```
the_stack->numbers[the_stack->size++]=number;
```

You never initialize the `size` member of your struct, so it's just random garbage, and you're going way out of bounds on the array. It also doesn't seem to make a lot of sense, since you also have a `top` member, which won't be updated if you do this. Seems like you should stick to either a `top` or a `size` member.